# ssh and sudo not working after wrong permission command

Tags: permissions, ssh

I connected to my droplet via shh and then accidentally run `sudo chmod a+rwx /.` command on the terminal in order to give write permission to a folder and its subfolders!

at first, I noticed sudo is not working

```
error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
```

then closed the terminal and tried to reconnect but ssh didn't work, either

> Permission denied (publickey)

How can I fix these issues? thanks..

Comment: I hope you have a backup.

Comment: unfortunately, nope! OS is in a droplet in digitalocean. I installed basic apps (nginx, postgresql, node, pm2). I cannot access db because it's not started and can't restart! I need my data first..

Comment: I'm really sorry about that. That is one of the benefits of running things on your own hardware. Does digitalocean have a web management panel for the droplets? Like with AWS EC2, there may be a way to start another droplet and mount the screwed filesystem in the new droplet and copy all the important data and programs over. Give that a try.

Comment: If ~/.ssh is not 0700 and ~/.ssh/authorized_keys is not 0600 you will NOT be able to use publickey authentication. You *may* get in with a password if it was previously enabled, but no guarantee. If you can get in and the system is still hobbling along it would be a long, painful process to set everything right.

Comment: It probably *can* be fixed, but the effort (several days!) is rarely worthwhile. You need a working system alongside to learn what the permission of every dir and file *should* be. Humans make typos, so such a laborious repair is unlikely to be perfetc. Much, much simpler to seek DigitalOcean support to recover your data, and start anew.

Answer (score 2):

Running chmod a+rwx on your whole / filesystem will destroy it. It purges all permissions and makes sudo and ssh useless. Always be careful when running chmod! I don't know any other way to fix this than reinstalling or restoring from a backup.

Comment: if I could reinstall everything, does it change permissions to default?

Comment: If you re-format your hard drive and re-install Ubuntu, it will be fixed because Ubuntu sets default permissions when you install it.